# Java Date to MongoDB insert and find

Tags: java, mongodb, date

I'm currently trying to insert and find Date which is inserted in MongoDB. I realised that MongoDB will convert date to UTC while storing in database. I'm using Javafx date picker for picking date.

This is my function for converting string to date

```
public static Date setTime(String strdate,int ch){
    int yr,mth,dt;
    yr=Integer.parseInt(strdate.substring(0,4));
    mth=Integer.parseInt((strdate.substring(5,7)));
    dt=Integer.parseInt(strdate.substring(8,10));
    Date date=new Date();
    if(ch==0) {
        date.setHours(0);
        date.setMinutes(0);
        date.setSeconds(0);
        date.setYear(yr - 1900);
        date.setMonth(mth - 1);
        date.setDate(dt);
    }
    else if(ch==1) {
        date.setHours(0);
        date.setMinutes(0);
        date.setSeconds(0);
        date.setYear(yr - 1900);
        date.setMonth(mth - 1);
        date.setDate(dt+1);
    }
    return date;
}
```

For storing

```
Date newdate=new Date();
String picked_date=""+date.getValue(); //date is DatePicker object
newdate= MyDateTime.setTime(picked_date,0);
Document doc=new Document();
doc.append("date",newdate);
coll.insertOne(doc);
```

Here, I'm retrieving using filters

```
 String findDate=""+datePicker.getValue();
 Date startdate= MyDateTime.setTime(findDate,0);
 Date nextdate=MyDateTime.setTime(findDate,1);
 Bson filter=Filters.and(Filters.gte("date",startdate),Filters.lt("date",nextdate));
 List<Document> ls = new ArrayList<Document>();
 coll.find(filter).into(ls);
 for (Document doc : ls
            ) {
System.out.println(doc.getDate("date").toString());
 }
```

Now, the problem is consider if I pick date from DatePicker I will get "2017-03-10"
Now, when I try find date with "2017-03-9" the record for 10 March get retrieved and for "2017-03-10" still same record retrieved. I'm still confused why same document is retrieved for both 9 and 10 dates.

Comment: Consider adding the relevant documents you are trying to query. What is your java version ?

Comment: I'm currently using java 8,and I'm querying on inserted document where I'm storing date...